# How can I get a EditText input added to a variable float?

Tags: java, android, variables, android-edittext

Can please somebody tell me how I cag get the `input` from a `EditText` added to a `variable` `float` that I can display somewhere else in my app after clicking a 'add' `button` ?
This is my `EditText` in the xml:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/depositInput"
    android:hint="enter a sum" />
```

And this is my `Button` in the same xml:

```
<Button
    android:text="add transaction
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/addDepositButton" />
```

And here is my attempt to get this done in the `class`:

```
public class AddMoneyTransaction extends AppCompatActivity {

Button addDepositButton;
EditText depositInput;
float inputValue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_money_transaction);

    addDepositButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addDepositButton);
    depositInput   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.depositInput);

    addDepositButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    // get EditText by id
                    (EditText) inputValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.depositInput);

                    float actualBalance + inputValue
                }
            });
}
}
```

I know that this does not work. That is the reason why I am asking. Please ignore that little formatting mistake with the `}` bracket (this is only at this post and not in the actual class). `Thank you.`

Answer (score 1):

```
float inputValueFloat = Float.parseFloat("" + inputValue.getText());
```

> `"" + inputValue.getText()` is for converting the inputted text into `String`
>
> `Float.parseFloat(String)` converts the `String` value to float

Answer (score 0):

Semi-pseudo code:

```
// get the view
(EditText) inputView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.depositInput);

// get the string inside the EditText
String inputStringValue = inputView.getText().toString();

// parse it to a long
long inputLongValue = Long.valueOf(inputStringValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove these lines...

```
// get EditText by id
                (EditText) inputValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.depositInput);

                float actualBalance + inputValue
```

and try this....

```
float number = Float.valueOf(depositInput.getText().toString());
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

What about retrieving the text contents, then converting it into a float?

```
CharSequence text = intputValue.getText();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text);
float f = Float.parseFloat(sb.toString());
```